# Predicting high values with keras and regression

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to build a regression model but the mse and mae are very high. I filter and normalize the data (both the input and output, and also the test and train set). I think the problem comes because I have very high values in one column: the minimum is 1 and the maximum is 9100000 (without normalizing), but I actually need to predict these high values.

The model looks like this: I have 6 input columns and 800000 rows. And I have tried with more neurons and layers, or changing the sigmoid function, but the loss and the error keep being around 0.8 for mse and 0.3 for mae. The predictions are also way lower than they should be, never achieving the high values.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=num_input, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Comment: You cannot predict such huge range with a sigmoid activation (which range is [0, 1]), you need to remove sigmoid here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few remarks/advices:

- RMSProp is generally not used with fully connected layers, I recommend switching to Adam or SGD.
- If you have a skewed distribution with many large values, you might consider using the log of these values instead.
- First try with a shallow model with few neurons. Then gradually increase the number of neurons in order to overfit the dataset. You should be able to reach perfect score on the train set. At that point you can start decrease the number of neurons and add layers with dropout to improve generalisation.
- As already mentioned in the comments, the output activation for regression should be "linear". Sigmoid is for binary classification.

Comment: Oh thanks! My loss has gone down to 0.2, so it is way better than in the beginning. The only thing is that my validation loss keeps being 0.8, while the training loss is 0.2. Does this really matter?

Comment: yes, you should look up the term "overfitting" on Google, you'll see that a high validation loss is an issue...